# Ubuntu 12.04 setting /etc/environment variables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

If I set a variable in /etc/environment, it only seems to apply to administrators while in sudo su.

How can I get the variables to apply to everyone? Especially when they are in terminal?

Comment: Have you checked the mode (permissions) of the `/etc/environment` file?  It should probably be set to 644 (`rw–r––r––`).

Comment: It set to: -rw-r--r--

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this may be to add the variables into /etc/.bashrc (assuming everyone is using a bash shell)

Comment: Um, are you sure that’s the file you mean?  Not `/etc/profile`?

Comment: @scott - Yes, I'm sure thats the file I meant, but after googling a bit, /etc/profile is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup variables to apply to everyone, the best place is neither /etc/environment nor /etc/profile, because they are system files -- messing them up will give you headaches when you system is upgraded.

Best approach:

- Create your own files under /etc/profile.d/,
- Give it a .sh extension
- make it executable (via chmod 755 file)

That's it. When you need to have similar setting on different boxes, or when it time to do a brand new installation, or any similar situation. Just backup/copy the file over, and you are done for the day.

HTH